# Is it possible to edit the query result in workbench?

Tags: mysql

I need to delete some records that comes out of the query result. But the query result is marked as `Read Only`. even when I query the primary key. The problem is my DB is so large (not much, 1.5 million record) that I can not right click on the table and choose `Edit table data` as I get the error no. 2008: `mysql client ran out of memory` which I could not solve (though, my pc has 8 GB RAM). My DB is loaded in the localhost so the client is the server. Please, help.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL Workbench is by default set into secure mode (they call it "Safe updates" mode) meaning that one cannot update or delete rows within SQL editor until WHERE clause with (primary) key or LIMIT parameter is not explicitly defined:

So the query:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE name='xyz'
```

will not work (will not really delete rows) until you define WHERE with PK:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id=100
```

or

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE name='xyz' LIMIT 1
```

To disable secure mode in Workbench go into Edit->Preferences->SQL Editor tab and uncheck "Safe updates" checkbox. But be careful then! :-)

Answer (score -1):

To edit a big table:

You can right click the ***"Send to SQL Editor -> SELECT All Statement"***.

Then before running, this, add a `LIMIT 100` in that `SELECT` or a `WHERE` condition to filter the rows returned.

You can also go to ***"Preferences -> SQL Editor"*** and mark the ***"Limit Rows"*** checkbox. If you set it to, say 1000, then the "Edit Table" command will fetch the first 1000 rows. You can then move to the next "page" by clicking on the "Fetch next frame of records from the data source" button.

---

Your other question:

It's not always possible to edit a result set. If it involves `GROUP BY` or data from more than one tables, then the result set may be Read-only. In that case, you could write a `DELETE` or `UPDATE` statement to do the deletion or updates for you.

Comment: But I need to view all rows. Is there a solution to view them as pages or something like that ?

Comment: Just wanted to add that it seems to be somewhat inconsistent in version 6.3. Sometimes I can edit a query result of a table with a PK and sometimes not. This is using a `SELECT * FROM dbname.tablename` written manually and with Send to SQL Editor Select All. Though this is on cleardb and seems to relate to if an extra null row is returned or not. If a null row is then it is editable.